# Excel 2010 - Open file with different locale

Tags: excel, locale

I work in a closed Windows environment and I am not able to change the Windows Locale.
I am going to receive on a regular basis excel files written in the French Locale and when I open them in my English Locale settings at work, the dates are changed. (from yyyy/mm/dd  to dd/mm/yyyy).

This is done automatically by Excel when opening the files so I was wondering if theres a way for Excel to open the file in its saved locale without converting it to my work locale?
It would save me alot of time because it would save me from having to check each file what format it should be and reformat the display settings.

I need for the open file to keep the original locale settings.